# Exception Wrapping possible?

Tags: java, exception

I have an Exception 'OrekitException' that I want to wrap into my own Exception class.

How can I go about this?

e.g. In one of my methods:

```
private void configureOrekit() throws OrekitException{
    try {
       method logic...
} catch (OrekitException oe) {
    System.out.println(OrekitException oe);
    log.error(oe.getMessage());
}
```

My own Exception class:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

       public MyException ( String message )
        {
            super( message );
        }
}
```

How can I incorporate OrekitException in MyException so whenever it is thrown, it's out of the MyException class?

Comment: Look up api doc for java.lang.Throwable. See where the constructor can take a Throwable called cause?  Pass in the exception you want to wrap as the cause argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a constructor  that also accepts the exception to wrap :

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

       public MyException (String message, OrekitException exception){
            super(message, exception);
        }
}
```

or to wrap any exception use a broader type for the parameter :

```
public MyException (String message, Exception exception){
    super(message, exception);
}
```

You could use it as :

```
private void configureOrekit() throws MyException{
    try {
       method logic...
} catch (OrekitException oe) {
   throw new MyException("message useful...", oe);       
}
```

Note that `System.out.println()` is not a way to trace an exception and that logging an exception **and** then wrap it in another exception that you throw is  not good as you could still log it at any layer, it would make things not clear at all to find some duplicate error logs in log files... 
In a general way, either log or throw/propagate the exception : not both.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions allow you to specify a `cause`. You can take a cause in your constructor, and pass it to `Exception`'s constructor:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

      public MyException (String message, Exception cause){
           super(message, cause);
      }
}
```

And your method can then throw `MyException`:

```
private void configureOrekit() throws MyException{
    try {
        method logic...
    } catch (OrekitException oe) {
        System.out.println(OrekitException oe);
        log.error(oe.getMessage());

        throw new MyException("", oe);
    }
}
```

This allows the stack trace from your `MyException` objects to have `caused by...` show details/trace of the original `OrekitException`